# Программное изменение стиля

Tags: java, android

У меня есть такой стиль

```
<style name="TextDefaultTheme" >
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/exo_2_bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
    </style>
```

Как можно его программно достать и изменить к примеру цвет и после навесить на `TextView`?

Comment: Никак. Всё, что в ресурсах находится - неизменяемо. Вам надо создавать по отдельной теме для каждого варианта цвета или вообще не использовать темы/стили.

Comment: А программно тоже нельзя как либо стиль создать? @ЮрийСПб

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Стили, как и все остальные ресурсы упаковываются в APK файл, а его содержимое никак нельзя поменять во время исполнения. Вообще да, сделать так, чтобы APK файл менял своё содержимое можно, как можно и почти всё остальное сделать, что только можно придумать, однако это предельно неправильный, безумно сложный и совершенно неоправданный процесс. Вам надо проектировать приложение с учётом ограничений языка, окружения и прочего. Некоторые вещи при этом, да, стандартными средствами не сделать и сделать их будет сложно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Просто у меня в приложении пользователи сами кастомизируют некоторые элементы интерфейса, и вот думаю как сделать эффективную смену интерфейса под настройки пользователя. Получается нет никакого выхода как вручную к примеру к каждому TextView выставлять цвет?

Comment: Вы можете не завязываться на ресурсах, которые предоставляет Вам платформа Android. Как вариант вы можете создать свои ресурсы, которые будете хранить в любом удобном для Вас формате (Например, json).
Созданный Вами JSON файл может проходить через какой-либо Адаптер (один из шаблонов проектирования), который будет генерировать Вам объект с нужно темой.
Это один из способов решения данной проблемы, уверен есть и другие способы.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте создать активити в котором будет несколько пунктов которые вы хотите чтобы пользователь мог кастомизировать по цвету к примеру, варианты цветов пропишите в ресурсах ну и соответственно в зависимости от выбора пользователя присваивайте переменной определенное число 1.2.3 и ТД и после сделайте проверку свичем в зависимости от того какое значение имеет переменная тот цвет и выбирать. 
У меня так реализована заливка в приложении, если необходимо могу скинуть код ближе к вечеру.